# ExceptionInInitializerError when running simple DL4J code

Tags: java, maven, deeplearning4j, dl4j

I'm currently trying to get dl4j (deeplearning4j) to import my model that I trained in keras 1.2.

This is my code:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    try {
        MultiLayerNetwork network = KerasModelImport.importKerasSequentialModelAndWeights(
                "C:\\Users\\A\\Documents\\GitHub\\DevanagriRecognizer\\model_keras1.h5");
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKerasConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedKerasConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I'm using Maven to handle the dependencies, and this is my first time using it. (That might be relevant)

When I run the above code I get a ExceptionInInitializerError caused by UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jnind4jcpu in java.library.path.

It looks like a missing dependency, but I have no idea how to fix it.

This is my pom.xml: https://pastebin.com/FzAMwA0z

And this is my full stacktrace: https://pastebin.com/a2kyUtch

By the way, I'm using IntelliJ with Java 1.8u101 on 64-bit Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, changing `dl4j.version` from 0.8.1-SNAPSHOT to 0.8.0 fixed it. Still not sure why, but it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I am not much into dl4j. But, multiple existing redirections to this one:

1. Possibly try specifying a classifier for `nd4j-native-platform` as:

   ```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>nd4j-native-platform</artifactId>
        <version>${dl4j.version}</version>
        <classifier>windows-x86_64</classifier>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Build using `maven-shade-plugin` following this configuration:
   https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/blob/master/dl4j-examples/pom.xml#L160
3. Or follow [this](https://github.com/CampagneLaboratory/variationanalysis/issues/1) for:

> The workaround consists in either:
>
> changing tmp permission changing tmp location.
>
> Define TMP, TMPDIR and
>   TEMP to a new directory, add -Djava.io.tmpdir=${TMPDIR} to the java
>   command.

Linking more sources to [troubleshoot](https://deeplearning4j.org/quickstart#troubleshooting) and its [wiki](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/wiki/Debugging-UnsatisfiedLinkError-on-Windows#using-dependency-walker).

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, keras isn't the problem here and isn't really relevant for this stack trace. You have bad dependencies on your LD_LIBRARY_PATH somewhere.

If you're using windows, look into:
https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/wiki/Debugging-UnsatisfiedLinkError-on-Windows

A common problem is MKL with anaconda. If you are using that, then another work around is to set library path to empty with:

-Djava.library.path=""

The above is called a System property. Set that in your runtime config if you have one.